# jQuery Mouseover only works on parent but not children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, mouseevent

I have a series of divs with the class of box. I want to hover on box-1, and then bring the corresponding image with the ID of img-1 to the foreground. The same goes for 2 and 3.

The interaction works well, except that when I hover on the p tags inside the box div, this wouldn't work: the `num` returns `NaN` instead of the number in the id. How do I fix this, so that when I hover on box-1 and the children of box-1, it triggers the function to bring the image forward? Please help. Thanks.

```js
    var num;
    $(".box").mouseenter(function(event){
     num = parseInt(event.target.id.split("-")[1]);
        $("#img-" + num).css("display", "block");
        $("#img-" + num).css("zIndex", 999);
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $("#img-" + num).css("display", "none");
        $("#img-" + num).css("zIndex", 0);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="box-1">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box-2">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box-3">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>caption</p>
        </div>
        <img id="img-1" style="display:none"/>
        <img id="img-2" style="display:none"/>
        <img id="img-3" style="display:none"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: First, you have to fix your syntax error.

Comment: Use `this.id` for the box id

Comment: @charlietfl great! it works. Do you want to write it down and I'll take it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your events on the parent "box" as well as the child `p` elements.

You don't need to worry about hovering over the child elements because when you do, you are also hovering over the parent. You also don't need to worry about bringing the images into the foreground, because the ones not displayed won't be present on the page in the first place.

Read the comments below:

```js
var num = null;
// JQuery recommends using .on() instead of shorthand event methods
// By setting the event on the parent box as well as the child <p>'s the problem is solved.
$(".box, .box p").on("mouseover", function(event){
  // .closest() takes a selector and looks for a match as the nearest ancestor 
  num = parseInt(this.closest(".box").id.split("-")[1]);
  $("#img-" + num).removeClass("hidden"); // Work with CSS classes not inline styles
});

$(".box, .box p").on("mouseout", function(){
  $("#img-" + num).addClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
.box { border:1px dashed grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="box-1">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box-2">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>caption</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box-3">
            <p>title</p>
            <p>caption</p>
        </div>
        <img id="img-1" class="hidden" alt="img-1">
        <img id="img-2" class="hidden" alt="img-2">
        <img id="img-3" class="hidden" alt="img-3">
    </div>
```